# Page is too slow because of background images

Tags: css, preload

I am using a CSS3 fullscreen gallery(no JavaScript) on one website. The gallery is basically an unordered list where each list item is one fullscreen background.

It works by setting the background-image in CSS file for each list item.Currently the gallery holds 48 images and the page takes too much to load.

First view is somewhere around 35 seconds. It seems that the browser first loads every DOM element, and it takes too much time.

Is there a way to not load some list item elements on page load, but make them visible only after the page has loaded?

The website can be seen at http://www.steveezell.com

Comment: how you managed to handle this slowness?

Comment: By doing a dirty hack, only a few images are loaded on page start so that the browser can render the page fairly quickly. Then I added the click event for the body which adds all other background images.

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring the image in the HTML source, it will be load always during the page load. I think the best option is to change the image source from JavaScript.

ps: nice page

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use AJAX calls after the page is fully loaded:

```
// Load the script when the page has fully loaded:

$(window).load( function() {
$.getScript(‘your_3rd_party-script.js’);
});
```

RetrieveImages.js:

```
// Load here all the images (You might consider showing the first image 
// or images with the regular page loading  to show a first indication to the user 
// and avoid waiting for the page to finish load before showing something).

document.getElementById("myImg").src = "http://www.example.com/image?id=1";
```

You probably should use jQuery grouping to load all the images by class `$(".className")`.

What is the serverside code you using? I would reccomand enabling gzip compression, which should reduce the images size dramatically.